# Spring tool suite IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

I am using spring tool suite IDE. I have imported one spring project. After running the project I get error as `Fatal error` compiling: tools.jar not found: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\..\lib\tools.jar`. I tried to use JDK's path in the preferences option. But then it shows another error as diamond operator is not supported in source 1.5. I am using JDK 8 and STS 3.6.3. Can anyone help me solving this error?

Comment: If you are missing tools.jar, you are likely using a JRE rather than the full JDK. Tweak your settings to use the JDK rather than the JRE (even the error message notes "jre8"). See "Development Files and Directories" in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get error as Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8..\lib\tools.jar.

Trying to use a JDK instead of JRE as you did is the right course of action for this error.

> But then it shows another error as diamond operator is not supported in source 1.5.

It is possible to use Java 8 as a runtime yet compile using Java 5 as source and/or target level. This is really independent of the chosen runtime.

Check that you select at least Java 7 for 'source' and 'target' level if you want to use the '<>' operator in your code. This setting can be found by right clicking on your project and going to 'Properties >> Java Compiler'.

You can change these settings right there... but... depending on your project's setup this may not be the best idea. For example if your project is a maven project then you should configure compiler settings via maven compiler's plugin as shown here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

If you change the settings directly in Eclipse's UI those settings may be lost as soon as maven updates your project.

Comment: hi.. You are right, My project is in maven. In my project I have selected Java 8. still it is showing the error as diamond operator is not supported in source 1.5. I think it is using Java 5 for compilation. You said that I have to configure settings in maven compiler's plugin. Can you tell how to do this settings.

Comment: Thanks Kris. I made the changes in the pom.xml and all worked fine. thank you

Answer (score 0):

For that project, RightClick -> Properties -> Project Facets -> Change the java version to Java 1.7.

The diamond operator (empty "`<>`") was introduced in 1.7.

Comment: I tried that, but it is showing the same error. Can you suggest some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Java version in the launch configuration wizard. Right-click on the project Run As -> Run Configurations... then select your project's launch config in the explorer on the left and check the contents of JRE tab on the right.
Also go to Preferences -> Java -> Compiler, ensure that Compiler Compliance Level is at to 1.7 at least.